# tomato puree - five a day

Tags: fruits

So it's accepted that tomato puree counts as one of your five a day (20g of double concentrate for example). What is the max you could have for it to still count? So could you have 40g and it would be two portions, or 100g and it's five?

Comment: Counts as one of your five a day of _what_? What is this number you're asking about?

Comment: Sorry, I meant recommended number fruit and veg.